# Where can I find a list of similar algebra formulas?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

Here is a simple formula:

$$(n - 1)\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n x_ix_j = \sum_{i = 1}^n\sum_{j = 1}^n(x_i - x_j)^{2}.$$

As a self-learner, I want to know what is the English word to describe this kind of formula? I tried to google "series formula", but seems not a proper word.

So what would be the proper word for this kind of formulas, so that I can get a list of them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Newton-Girard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) formulae.

Comment: There appears to be an error, since the second summation does not have a summation on $j$. Nonetheless, the term "symmetric functions" comes to mind.

Comment: @martycohen: sorry it's a typo. I corrected that. Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have written is a "[summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_%28mathematics%29)" (or, less precisely, a "summation formula"). You can find [many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_identities#Identities) [lists](https://web.archive.org/web/20221006172044/https://polysum.tripod.com/) [of](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series) [summation](http://functions.wolfram.com/GeneralIdentities/12/) [identities](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506223446/http://sun.iwu.edu/%7Ethe/DM13323.pdf) [with a bit of internet searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=list%20of%20summation%20identities).